# Need help in retrieving text of a tooltip with Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, text, tooltip

I am trying to get the text of the tooltip in the following image - with the code snippet shown below.

[image]

```
String xPath = "//div[@class="tooltip-inner"]/div";                 
we = driver.findElement(By.xPath(xPath));
                        
if (null != we) {
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);                    
    action.moveToElement(we).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPath))).click().build()
                            .perform();

    String actualText = we.getText();
} else {
....generate an error
}
```

The code does not throw an error, but at the same time, text is not retrieved.

I tried to locate the /p and the /ul child elements and get their texts - but no luck either.

What am I not doing right? Any ideas?

Thanks.
-S-

Comment: getText() will only get the contents of non-nested text.  (For instance, that <strong> tag and it's contents are read as another node so no text will be returned from the parent element... it would work on the <strong> element itself....) So your xpath should go further down the path... /p/strong.  (or use getAttribute("innerHTML") and parse.)

Comment: After some trials, I was successful in navigating to the /p and /ul/li elements and retrieve the text for the tool-tip.  Thank you, @pcalkins.